# How filling area with different colors in angular2, d3.js?

Tags: angular, d3.js, svg

I made graphic in svg and d3.js on angular2. [This is picture of graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nsI4.png). In picture fact line is blue and plan value is dashed white.
Now need filling this graphic area with two colors(red and green).
When fact values more than plan values, fill red,
if plan values more than fact values, fill green.
I have one option for doing this:
Using gradient for colors. But I can't determine stop point for gradient.

this is my code in angular .ts file:

```
interface Point {
    x: number;
    y: number;
    x1: number;
    y1: number;}

getLinePointsArea () {
    return this.plan.values.map((val, i) => {
        return {
            x: i * this.lengthX,
            y: val,
            x1: i * this.lengthX,
            y1: this.fact.values[i]
        };
    })
}

getArea(){
    let points = this.getLinePointsArea();
    let area = d3.svg.area<Point>()
    .x(d => { return d.x })
    .y(d => { return d.y })
    .x1(d => { return d.x1 })
    .y1(d => { return d.y1 })
    .interpolate('cardinal');
    return area(points);
}

getPolygonPathArea () : string {
    let path = this.getArea();
    return path;
}
```

And my code .html

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="lineChart" width="100%" height="100%">
<defs>
    <linearGradient id="planBg">
         <!-- <stop *ngFor="let s of stopData" [attr.offset]="s.offset" [ngClass]="s.style" /> -->
        <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:#321F2A;stop-opacity:1" />
        <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color: transparent;stop-opacity:1" />
    </linearGradient>
</defs>
<g id="main" [attr.transform]="'translate('+padding.join(' ')+')'">
    <g id="main" [attr.transform]="'translate(120, 120)'">
        <g id="plan-gradient">
            <path [attr.d]="getPolygonPathArea()" fill="url(#planBg)"></path>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
```

What solutions do you have? Or how find stop position for gradient?
Sorry for my english. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to just have one svg element on your html template,
make functions like "draw(...)", "update(...)" and so on in your .ts file,
and implement your d3 logic right in there like normal javascript,
otherwise you will have too less benefit of d3 usage and too much complexity in my opinion.